# Raspberry Pi 4b can't start executable file

Tags: minecraft

I have recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4b and wanted to play around with minecraft-pi edition. I downloaded the latest version of it and when i try to run it by double clicking, it at first asks me if i want to execute it in the terminal or just execute, but no matter what I click on, it does nothing, the program doesn't start. I then tried to execute it by cd-ing into the directory and then typing ./minecraft-pi, but then it gives me this error:

`./minecraft-pi: error while loading shared libraries: libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

What should i do?

Edit: I already googled the error and similar stuff to it, but there was nothing that helped me.

Comment: you should google the error message

Comment: Try this version https://gitea.thebrokenrail.com/TheBrokenRail/minecraft-pi-reborn

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, on the Pi, they changed the name of those libraries:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/vc/lib $ ls -l /opt/vc/lib/*brcm*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 202072 Jul  3 10:07 /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmEGL.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 105768 Jul  3 10:07 /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  99208 Sep 22  2016 /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmOpenVG.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  78532 Jul  3 10:07 /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmWFC.so
```

You should be able to create a link with the old name:

```
cd /opt/vc/lib
sudo ln -s libbrcmEGL.so libEGL.so
sudo ln -s libbrcmGLESv2.so libGLESv2.so
sudo ln -s libbrcmOpenVG.so libOpenVG.so
sudo ln -s libbrcmWFC.so libWFC.so
```

At least, they will find the libraries. I don't know if anything else changed, so your minecraft may not work anyway, but it's worth a  try.

Comment: Do other programs work?